# IdentityServer4 - TokenEndpoint is always null when running in docker container

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I am running IdentityServer4 (`identity-service`) in a docker swarm container. This is the service setup in my stack file:

```
  identity-service:
    image: identity:${TAG:-latest}
    environment:
      - DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb://mongo:27017
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:8080
      - LOGGING_LEVEL=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    networks:
      - proxy
      - database
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
        failure_action: rollback
        order: start-first
      labels:
        - com.df.notify=true
        - com.df.servicePath=${SERVICE_PATH:-/identity}
        - com.df.port=8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 10s
```

I am also using `IdentityModel2.Client` to request tokens. This is also done in `identity-service` through another endpoint: `/user/login`. This is how I use `DiscoveryClient`:

```
    var discoveryDocument = await new DiscoveryClient(hostUrl).GetAsync();
    if (discoveryDocument.IsError) {
        throw new Exception(
            String.Format("Failed to find discovery document at url: {0}, received following token-endpoint: {1}",
            hostUrl, discoveryDocument.TokenEndpoint));
    }
    return new TokenClient(discoveryDocument.TokenEndpoint, "Web", authorizationSecret);
```

This works fine if I don't run this in a container, but throws `Exception` when running in swarm as `discoveryDocument.TokenEndpoint` is **null** for some reason. I have also tried to shell into the container just to see if I can access `http://0.0.0.0:8080/.well-known/openid-configuration` with curl, which I do.

(`hostUrl` is `http://0.0.0.0:8080` when running in container)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by not using `DiscoveryClient`. Instead I am giving `TokenClient` the URL to token-endpoint directly as follows:

```
new TokenClient(String.Concat(hostUrl, "/connect/token"), "Web", authorizationSecret);
```

Where `hostUrl` is provided by environment variables and is set to `http://127.0.0.1` in my docker-stack file. For some reason, this works...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using IdentityServer with the client.
In Startup, AddDeveloperSigningCredential was missing which caused the problem.